# Getting images from sub-directory to show

Tags: php

I am trying to make a latest news system with the possibility to select a featured image from the directory where all those images are. Let me show you what I got

```
<?php
$files = glob("../assets/images/newsimages/*.*");
 var_dump($files);
 for ($i = 0; $i < count($files); $i++) {
    
   $image = $files[$i];
   $supported_file = array(
    'gif',
    'jpg',
    'jpeg',
    'png'
    );

$ext = strtolower(pathinfo($image, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

if (in_array($ext, $supported_file)) {
echo '<option value="'. $image .'">' . basename($image) . '</option>';
} else {
continue;
}
}
?>
```

The problem I am running into is that I want to load the images in the admin without ../assets/images/ because when I post this it will come ../assets/images/newsimages/img.jpg in the news table in the database. I want to load the $files like assets/images/newsimages/

Answer (score 0):

You can use "GLOB_BRACE" like and specify the correct folders:

```
glob("{dir1/*.php,dir2/*.php}",GLOB_BRACE);
```

Remember that this solution has limitations on some non GNU systems, like Solaris or Alpine Linux!

Or you can go the old way with **opendir**. This may be a safer path in the future because the directory structure may evolve apart from the source code.